# Why do Chinese characters in JSON cause "bad control character" error with JSON.parse?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jquery, utf-8

I have a standard HTML5-type client/server set up. The server side is all Java, and the client side is JavaScript. Using ajax I send queries and receive replies. Up to now, I've had no problems with `JSON.parse(data)`. However, I have a new user who entered her last name using Chinese characters. This is causing a "JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal" error on the client side.

The server builds a reply as follows (exception handling omitted):

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject();
jsono.put("last_name", last_name);
jsono.put("first-name", first_name);
String response = jsono.toString();
```

The client receives something like:

```
{"last_name":"Smith","first_name":"Bob"}
```

The reply is displayed on a web page which is set to  `<meta charset="utf-8">`:

```
var theResult = JSON.parse(data);
$('#first_name').html(theResult.first_name);
```

This works just fine. However, for the Chinese user, the client receives

```
{"last_name":"唐","first_name":"Bob"}
```

and this causes the json.parse error.

I've now started looking at other characters. For example, `Andrés` does not cause an error, but also does not display properly. It looks like `Andr�s`.

So, I'm clearly missing something. Could someone enlighten me where the problem lies (e.g., is it server side? client side? JavaScript? jquery? html?) and how to solve it?

Comment: actually it is not a JavaScript problem, I think you use Java on the server-side, and it is related to your `JSONObject API` not client-side, if you really use Java add the tag then wait for my answer.

Comment: As Mehran said, it's not JSON or JavaScript. It's almost certainly an encoding problem. If the encoding is correct and everything knows what that encoding is, that works. (Example: http://jsbin.com/eParenUK/1/edit). So for example, if your JSON is returned to the browser using the Windows-1252 charset (or UTF-16, or...) instead of UTF-8...

Comment: I added the [java] tag. The server side is all Java. The production version runs on Linux; my development version runs on Mac.

Comment: How are you writing the `response` for the client?

Comment: I first write the header info (`HTTP/1.0 200 OK  Connection: close  Server: ServerName  Content-Type: text/html`) and then `try {output.writeBytes(response);` Now that you mention it, I suspect `text/html` is relevant.

Comment: And what class is the `output` object?

Comment: @RPW check the answer out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most useful libraries in Java I have used are `Gson API` and [JSONObject](http://json.org/java/) and both can handle this issue, then if you this your problem is probably solved. just be careful all the utf-8 related params here are really important:

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject();
jsono.put("last_name", "唐");
jsono.put("first-name", firstName);
String myjsonString = jsono.toString();

//write your output
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myjson.txt"));
out.write(myjsonString.getBytes("utf-8"),0, myjsonString.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
```

Comment: Not quite working yet. I'm using a `DataOutputStream` (called `out`) to return the response. I've added the headers `out.writeBytes("Character-Encoding: utf-8");` and `out.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`. I then call `out.write(myjsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, myjsonString.getBytes("UTF-8").length);` In the console, the object sent back looks fine, but this produces a `JSON.parse: unexpected character` error.

Comment: OK, got it working, but don't understand why! I changed the http headers back to txt/html but kept the `out.write(myjsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, myjsonString.getBytes("UTF-8").length);` statement. Now, both the Chinese characters and the accented e show up.

Comment: this is all about how to java web-servers make their HTTP responses, the important thing here is using the right character-encoding. have a good Christmas. :)

Comment: Downvoting because as I thought OP was not using servlet API, which is presented in this answer. `DataOutputStream#writeBytes` is writing only the first (lower) byte from string characters, that was the whole problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Pavel Horal: thanks for the comment and downvote, I have updated my answer.

Comment: This might be working - still an explanation would make it more useful.